# C# ASP.NET work with Google.Authenticator

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-authenticator

I am currently develop an new page for my web application using C# asp.net.
My purpose is to use google authenticator as a 2FA authentication.

Below is my code.

```cs
using Google.Authenticator;

Dictionary<String, String> result = new Dictionary<String, String>();
TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
var setupInfo = tfa.GenerateSetupCode("XXXX", "TITLEXXX", "CODEXXXX", 300, 300);

var result = tfa.ValidateTwoFactorPIN("XXSSWWW", "XXXXWWW");
```

But in `tfa.GenerateSetupCode` and  `tfa.ValidateTwoFactorPIN` there is an error as below show.

> The type "Object" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstand. version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I tried to search online for the solutions. What I have tried:

- Change my web application Target Framework from .NetFramework 4.6.1 to .NetFramework 4.8
- Uninstall and reinstall Google.Authenticator 3.0.0 nuget package.

But above action is not helping me to solve the solution. Anyone know what the issue is and how to solve it?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're using [BrandonPotter
/
GoogleAuthenticator](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/GoogleAuthenticator/tree/master)? You may want to mention that in your question.

Comment: @RobIII Yes.. You are right.

Comment: The error seems quite straightforward? `You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard. version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

Comment: @RobIII yes.. but may I know how to add ? As I coudnt find it either in Add Reference, or nuget package

Comment: It's [explained by wakasupi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75940240/215042)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package. Right click on your Project in Visual Studio and Browse for NETStandard.Library
[image]

Comment: Still same issue after I install NetStandardLibrary as you show.